# sizing a width by VW units while assuring a minimum width

Tags: css, viewport-units

How can I size a DIV with a vw units on the upper size BUT assure a minimum width of at least 100px?

```
.container {
    min-width:1000px;
    width: 85vw;
}
```

Is not working...

Comment: There is no reason that shouldn't work.. I tested it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MP3Uj/show/), and it seems to work.

Comment: well-  its not working for me. Wonderful, I guess that means I have missed something somewhere - it is going to be a fun night.  Thank you.

Comment: no this worked.  I am stupid, and had a typo - which wasn't presented in this snippet here.  I should learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original code worked fine:

```
.container {
    min-width:1000px;
    width: 85vw;
}
```

Comment: Nothing to see here.  My bug was caused by something else.  Perhaps this question should be deleted, but I thought the viewport tag answer may be useful to someone someday

Answer (score 1):

maybe you forgot this

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```